# R calculated variable from integer variable - how?

Tags: r, int, calculated-field

I have a variable (HTB) which is an integer - it can have a value of either 1 or 2.

I have done some calaculations which have involved aggregating HTB by user name - so I know how often the user got a 1 or a 2 response

The resulting data frame therefore displays variables `HTB.1` and `HTB.2`

I would like to calculate the percentage of HTB=2 for each user but this

```
results$HTBpercent<-results$HTB.2/(results$HTB.1+results$HTB.2)*100
```

does not work (presumably because it is really one variable)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have something like:

```
df <- aggregate(c(1,1,2,2), list(c(1,2,1,2)), FUN=table)
df

#  Group.1 x.1 x.2
#1       1   1   1
#2       2   1   1
```

...where `df$x` is a `matrix`, like:

```
df$x
#     1 2
#[1,] 1 1
#[2,] 1 1
```

Therefore,

```
df$perc2 <- df$x[,"2"] / rowSums(df$x)
df

#  Group.1 x.1 x.2 perc2
#1       1   1   1   0.5
#2       2   1   1   0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to group by user-name and realize that you probably only have one HTB-variable and that R does not use periods as selection operators. Perhaps (assuming you want these percentages replicated within each user-id):

```
 results$HTBpercent<- with(results, ave( HTB, userID, function(x) 100*sum( x==2)/length(x) ) )
```